# Page refresh clears all the data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, socket.io

I'm working on basic chat-application running on express.js and socket.io.

**Server-side code:**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
var path = require("path");
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
    console.log("Server listening");
})

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("chat");
})

io.sockets.addListener("connection", function(socket) {
    socket.addListener("chat-message", function(message, nickname) {
        io.sockets.emit("chat-message", message, nickname)
    })
})
```

**Client-side code:**

```
var socket = io();
var nickname = prompt("Whats your name?");

var input = document.getElementById("text-input");
var container = document.getElementById("chat-container");

input.addEventListener("keydown", function() {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (input.value !== "") {
            socket.emit("chat-message", nickname + ": " + input.value);
            input.value = "";
        }
    }  
})

socket.addEventListener("chat-message", function(message) {
    container.innerHTML += message + "</br>";
})
```

Is there any way to avoid deleting info from the webpage after refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save all the messages and nicknames in a globar variable and send them on every new connection to the socket.

```
var messages = [];    
io.sockets.addListener("connection", function(socket) {
  //send messages to new connection     
  socket.addListener("chat-message", function(message, nickname) {
    messages.push({message: message, nickname: nickname});  
    io.sockets.emit("chat-message", message, nickname)
   })
})
```

**[Edit]**
Client Side

```
socket.addEventListener("chat-previous-messages", function(messages) {
    for(let i = 0; i < messages.length; i++){
       container.innerHTML += messages[i].message + "</br>";
    }
})
```

Server side

```
var messages = [];    
io.sockets.addListener("connection", function(socket) {
  socket.emit('chat-previous-messages', messages); //new code     
  socket.addListener("chat-message", function(message, nickname) {
    messages.push({message: message, nickname: nickname});  
    io.sockets.emit("chat-message", message, nickname)
   })
})
```

Or you can serve the chat page with the messages already displayed

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
   res.render("chat", messages);
})
//in the html part something like this
#chat-container
    - each message in messages
      message.message + '<br>'
```

Comment: Do you mean I have to export _messages_ to the my **main.js** file? If yes, explain please what's the best way to do it?

Comment: I meant tat every time you receive a message you can push its data into **messages**, you can use this variable to store all the messages received since the server started. Then on every new connection to the socket or even on every new request to the chat page you can send the stored messages to the client either using the socket or passing to the chat page like res.render("chat", {messages: messages})

Comment: I got what you meant by setting the _messages_ but I still didn't get how to implement them and connect with the **main** piece of code. If you are able to connect server-side to the **main** file — which I provided above (non-server piece of code) — I will be really grateful to You.

Comment: Check the edit, hope you understand what I mean and that it can be of any use

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and attention!